# Data from the SQLIte is not retriving in recycler view

Tags: android, sqlite

fragment class

```
public class My_Health extends Fragment {

DatabaseHandler db;

protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

    RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardlist_home);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardlist_home);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new HomeCardAdapter(db.getAllData(), R.layout.cardview_home));


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.addrecordfab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddRecord.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
}
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public List<UserInfo> getAllData() {
    List<UserInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    UserInfo bean = null;

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int index0 = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
        int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MOBILE_NO);
        int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DIAGNOSIS);

        String date = cursor.getString(index0);
        String mobile_no = cursor.getString(index1);
        String heading = cursor.getString(index2);
        bean = new UserInfo(date,mobile_no,heading);
        list.add(bean);
    }
    return list;
}

}
```

when I run the app it stops

logcat

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot/com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.helper.DatabaseHandler.getAllData()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.helper.DatabaseHandler.getAllData()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                   at com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.fragment.My_Health.onCreateView(My_Health.java:55)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling

```
db.getAllData()
```

in the line

```
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new HomeCardAdapter(db.getAllData(),R.layout.cardview_home));
```

but have not initialised db

Comment: Thanks
but now the recycler view is not showing . there is blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

the `recycler view` is not showing anything cause the `items.size` in your `recyclerview adapter` must be returning 0.

Comment: @DolleTulsihaha yes  that was the condition and i have already figured out.